# Why am I getting syntax errors on this display line?

Tags: java, syntax

I am getting some expression errors and symbols expected errors with the following line of code and cant figure out why.

```
System.out.println( "Hourly Rate: " money.format(myEmployee.getHourlyRate() ) );
```

Comment: Start by reading the message of the error.

Comment: SO isn't a compiler; those tell you what the problem with your syntax is.

Answer (score 2):

Because you need a `+` to concatenate your two values inside the print statement.

```
System.out.println( "Hourly Rate: " +  money.format(myEmployee.getHourlyRate() ) );
```